# How to get the rows with non-zero value in specific columns in a pipe delimited file using awk?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a pipe delimited file like below

```
TEST|RALPH|JACKSON|2|3|1
TEST|STEVE|PARKER|0|1|1
TEST|MARK|WOODS|0|1|1
TEST|DAVE|KNIGHT|1|3|1
TEST|JOHN|DOE|0|1|1
```

I want to filter the rows with non-zero value in columns 4,5 and 6 write it in a separate file.

Expected output

```
TEST|RALPH|JACKSON|2|3|1
TEST|DAVE|KNIGHT|1|3|1
```

I tried the following awk achieve this

```
awk -F "|" '$4 != 0 && $5 !=0 && $6 !=0' input.txt > output.txt
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this using awk.

Comment: That awk solution is perfectly fine and makes it clear what the intent is.  Sometimes clarity of intent is as important as code efficiency.  You could probably create a regex to match... but then someone would end up with the headache of understanding it at a later date!

Comment: You can multiply them `awk -F\| '$4 * $5 * $6'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current approach is correct, clear, and works as advertised, there is no real need to change it.

However, if you wanted to test even more columns, say *all* columns after column 3, this could possibly lead to a somewhat long `awk` program (if there were many columns).

Another way to do that would be to use a loop:

```
$ awk -F '|' '{ for (i=4; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == 0) next; print }' file
TEST|RALPH|JACKSON|2|3|1
TEST|DAVE|KNIGHT|1|3|1
```

This `awk` program tests the values of all columns after column 3 and skips the current line as soon as a column whose value is zero is found. If no zero is found, the current line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
k=open('k.txt','r')
for i in k:
    h=i.strip().split('|')
        if "0" not in h[-3:]:
            print "|".join(h)
output

python script.py

TEST|RALPH|JACKSON|2|3|1
TEST|DAVE|KNIGHT|1|3|1
```